# Basic Angular 2 Typescript Service Setup

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm starting in on converting an Angular 1 project to Angular 2 and am having some problems getting my first service set up. I set up a plunkr that matches what I'm trying to do and it's totally bombing out. Here's the plunkr:

https://plnkr.co/edit/oYrg68HhTihPFAcSGU8t?p=preview

In the actual app I'm using the angular CLI generator and getting the following error:

> Error: Typescript found the following errors:
>   /path/to/project/tmp/broccoli_type_script_compiler-input_base_path-bvDJA9MD.tmp/0/src/app/+login/login.component.spec.ts (17, 21): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call
>   target.

If anybody out there can help me get the plunkr working, that'd be great!

Here's the spec file if that's useful:

```
/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */

import { By }           from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';

import {
  beforeEach, beforeEachProviders,
  describe, xdescribe,
  expect, it, xit,
  async, inject
} from '@angular/core/testing';

import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

describe('Component: Login', () => {
  it('should create an instance', () => {
    let component = new LoginComponent();
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: It seems the constructor of the `LoginComponent` needs some arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's](https://plnkr.co/edit/69FWxhFVD98PHcU92na7?p=preview) a modified version of your plunkr that is working for me.

Seems that you need to provide the `TestService` and then pass it into your constructor as a parameter.

Updated app.ts.

```
//our root app component
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {TestService} from './test.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [ TestService  ],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <p><a (click)="logIn('test-user', '123456')">Test Login</a></p>
      <p>{{status}}</p>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {

  constructor(
    private testService:TestService;) {
    this.name = 'Pizza';
    this.status = 'Sword';

  }

  logIn(username, password) { 
    this.status = this.testService.logIn(username, password);
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that fixed the plunkr! Wasn't sure if I needed to provide the service in the @Component decorator, so lesson learned there. And thanks for catching the syntax issue with the constructor.

As it turns out, that didn't fix my actual app, but it narrowed it down enough for me to realize it was something in the test spec causing the issue. I commented out the spec file for the time being and now I'm up and running again.

Comment: @curiousgage Glad to hear it!  Good luck!